# How to use for loop in this case

Tags: for-loop

How can I rewrite this code ? I want to use for loop . If my score will increase about 2 points my game will add extra bomb. I dont wnat to copy cody for every 2 points

```
if(this.score == 2){
 this.bomb.create(Phaser.Math.RND.between(0, 3200), Phaser.Math.RND.between(0, 2200), 'bomba2');
 } else if (this.score == 4){
 this.bomb.create(Phaser.Math.RND.between(0, 3200), Phaser.Math.RND.between(0, 2200), 'bomba2');
 } else if (this.score == 6){
 this.bomb.create(Phaser.Math.RND.between(0, 3200), Phaser.Math.RND.between(0, 2200), 'bomba2');
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering this language is C-style (I'm guessing Java?), I would suggest doing something along the lines of

```
for (int i = 2; i += 2; i < {whatever value you want goes here}) {
    this.bomb.create(Phaser.Math.RND.between(0, 3200), Phaser.Math.RND.between(0, 2200), 'bomba2');
}
```

that should be about it considering what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you , JavaScript using Phaser3

Comment: @ocko if this solved your question you should be able to mark it as the answer.